# SQL Server Log:Error 18456, Severity: 14, State:8 and Visual Studio terminal : undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server, server

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2017. I've tried many different solutions.
the server is set to mixed mode.

The server states in the log files:

> Login failed for user
> Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only

I checked the server and the settings are set to mixed mode.

Here is my code:

```
var sql    = require('mssql');

var config = {
         server: "server",
         authenticationType: "Integrated",
         user: "",
         password: "",
         options: {
           encrypt: true,
           database: 'TEST',  
           tdsVersion: '7_1'
    }
};

sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query("SELECT * FROM tablee", function(err, recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
        
    });
});
```

I tried it with a username and password but also without it. The connection to the SQL Server database is not established. I set the encryption to true or false.

In the terminal of my IDE it says: "undefined".

What am I doing wrong, can someone help me please?

Comment: *"An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only"* The error is literally telling you the problem here; you can't use SQL Authentication when you're configured to integrated security only. You're passing a `user` and `password` in your connection string, so you're using SQL Authentication here.

Comment: *"I checked the server and the settings are set to mixed mode."* Have you restarted the instance after changing the setting? If not, do so. If yes, then either is it not in mixed, or you're connecting to the wrong server.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I just checked again and the server is set to mixed mode and has been restarted. I tried without specifying the user and password.
sorry i'm new to this field.it just doesn't work

Comment: If you're adamant that the server is set to mixed, then you aren't connecting to the right instance; the one you are trying to connect to is certainly in Integrated Only. You'll need to check the connection details you have for your instance and correct them.

Comment: where can i check the connection details for the instance? wherever i looked they are on mixed mode

Comment: No, the host and instance name. You can get that by using `@@SERVERNAME` on the instance.

Comment: I checked that and in fact I get a different name than the one I want to connect to.
I tried to establish a connection there, but that doesn't work either